# Checking if two variables match

Tags: php, variables

I'm trying to echo out a message if two variables match based on the logged in user ID and the page ID. I've been trying for hours and can't seem to get the final outcome to work.

I've tried using == every which way but I keep "OK" no matter what page I'm on.

What does work:
In the code below, $userNowId gives me the User ID of the current session. $profileID gives me the ID of the specific page ID. THIS WORKS.

Both these values echo out on the page correctly. For example if I'm logged in as User ID 1, and type in the url profile.php?user=65 to go to their page, my database ID (1) AND the url ID (65) both echo as they should.

The problem:
Now I'd like to make an if statement that says something like if these two values don't match, echo message "not your profile." Not sure if this helps but I've written this in OOP PHP.

Here's what I've got as of now.

```
<?php
    require_once 'core/init.php';

    $userNow = new user();
    $userNow->LoggedInUser();

    if (!$username = input::get('user')) {
        redirect::to('index.php');
    } else {
        $user = new user($username);
        if (!$user->exists()) {
            redirect::to(404);
        } else {
            $data = $user->data();
            $userNowId = ($_SESSION && $data->id);
            $profileID = ($data->id);

            if ($userNowId == $profileID) {
                echo "Your profile";
            } else {
                echo "Not your profile!";
            }
```

Comment: This gives me the user id of the current session within the database using a function.

Comment: I don't think so. That is a boolean expression.

Comment: I have read this code few times and I still can't understand what it is supposed to do. Why are there 2 `user` objects? Why do you do `!$username = input::get('user')`? Why is `$userNowId` a boolean?

Comment: When I echo the function it seems to work. Maybe I'm missing something! And yeah $username is defined in init.php.

Comment: !$username = input::get('user') pulls the username data for the user id page I'm visiting. This works as well as it should.

Comment: Got it, Tim! So I guess my question is how would I format this better so I can check if the two variables are equal? I've been trying many different methods and none seem to work!

Comment: Did you mean to write `$userNowId = ($userNow->id);`?

Comment: @tim `$userNowId` can only be `true`/`false`, it is a boolean.

Comment: @tim Do a var_dump instead https://ideone.com/Kp70lD

Comment: So any thoughts on how to fix this? The code I'm using just says "Your Profile" no matter what "page" I'm on:                                                    
if ($userNowId == $profileID) {
                echo "Your profile";
            } else {
                echo "Not your profile!";
            }

Comment: Yes. Fix the value of `$userNowId`. Whatever it was supposed to be it was definitely not supposed to be a boolean. Your if statement is literally always going to be `if(true)`

Comment: @Dharman thank you!!! I just couldn't pin-point where the error was. Thank you thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you are setting `$userNowId`

```
$userNowId = ($_SESSION && $data->id);
```

This is a boolean operation and will set the value to a boolean true or false, not an ID. I suspect what you really wanted is something like this:

```
$userNowId = array_key_exists('id', $_SESSION) ? (int)$_SESSION['id'] : null;
$profileID = (int)$data->id;

if ($userNowId === $profileID) {
  echo "Your profile";
} else {
  echo "Not your profile!";
}
```

Note that I have used strict type comparison (`===`) to prevent the `null` being converted to a `0`, which would be a security risk. I have also casted the id to integer so that the strict type check will work when PHP converts database int's to strings as it does.

Comment: thank you! I actually ended up using going with something slightly different and it works beautifully!.... if($_SESSION['user'] == $profileID){   
          echo $_SESSION["user"];
        } else {
          echo "Not your profile!";
        }

Comment: @TjOlmsy if this answered your question could you please accept it as the answer.